# JMeter post-processor extracting javascript after evaluation from response body

Tags: jmeter, post-processor

The response body from a POST contains the following javascript:

```
var now = new Date();
document.location.href="/wwtb/entry.cgi?id=148e2743ad01572d55265c96ae91dc6c&uid=qastudent&fromlogin=1&ts=" + now.getTime();
```

I need to extract the value of ts after it's evaluated so that I can pass it as a parameter in my next GET.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

Therefore you will not be able to extract the value "after it's evaluated" because it will never get evaluated.

JMeter's equivalent of [Date.getTime() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) is [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) so if you put the following construction anywhere in your Test Plan:

```
/wwtb/entry.cgi?id=148e2743ad01572d55265c96ae91dc6c&uid=qastudent&fromlogin=1&ts=${__time()}
```

The `${__time()}` bit will become substituted with the current timestamp in the runtime:

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept.